# Insert bytea into postgresql json type

Tags: json, postgresql

I am trying with no success to insert a byte array in a postgresql json type as one of the json columns. is it possible? does anyone have an example?

Comment: Why would you want to insert bytes instead of text in such a column? Can you post the code you're using (esp. the part that fails)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't, at least natively.  JSON only allows 3 basic primative data types:  number, string, and boolean.  Everything else must be serialized to a string or number.

This means that you have three basic options:

1. Serialize to hexadecimal.  The advantage is that it becomes easy to turn into a bytea in PostgreSQL if you need it.
2. Serialize to base64.  The advantage here is that it uses up less space.
3. Serialize to a number array.  This is not preferred in my view since it is hard to constrain each number to between 0 and 255.

Comment: when you say JSON allows 3 data types, are you referring to the values in a JSON object?