# PostgreSQL throws "column is of type jsonb but expression is of type bytea" with JPA and Hibernate

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, jpa, jsonb

This is my entity class that is mapped to a table in `postgres` (9.4)
I am trying to store metadata as `jsonb` type in the database

```
@Entity
@Table(name = “room_categories”)
@TypeDef(name = “jsonb”, typeClass = JsonBinaryType.class)
public class RoomCategory extends AbstractEntity implements Serializable {
    private String name;
    private String code;
    @Type(type = "jsonb")
    @Column(columnDefinition = "json")
    private Metadata metadata;

}
```

This is the metadata class:

```
public class Metadata implements Serializable {
    private String field1;
    private String field2;

}
```

I have used following migration file to add `jsonb` column:

```
databaseChangeLog:
– changeSet:
id: addColumn_metadata-room_categories
author: arihant
changes:
– addColumn:
schemaName: public
tableName: room_categories
columns:
– column:
name: metadata
type: jsonb
```

I am getting this error while creating the record in `postgres`:
ERROR: column “metadata” is of type `jsonb` but expression is of type `bytea`
Hint: You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.

This is the request body i am trying to persist in db:

```
  {
    “name”: “Test102”,
    “code”: “Code102”,
    “metadata”: {
    “field1”: “field11”,
    “field2”: “field12”
    }
    }
```

Please help how to convert `bytea` type to `jsonb` in java spring boot app

Comment: possible duplicate of : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20401719/insert-bytea-into-postgresql-json-type... 

kindly visit above link.

Comment: @Arihant Jain: I am too facing such issue. Did u resolved urs?

Answer (score 15):

Simply convert your object by an ObjectMapper to a json string and then use (::jsonb) as cast to jsonb type:

```
INSERT INTO room_categories (name, code, metadata)
    VALUES (?, ?, ? ::jsonb );
```

(you will need to use native queries to query data stored as jsonb)

Answer (score 8):

if you use the **JpaRespository** save interface method, you can add the cast method above the issue property

```
@ColumnTransformer(write = "?::jsonb")
private Metadata metadata;
```

Answer (score 4):

### The cause of the error

You could get this PostgreSQL:

> ERROR: column “metadata” is of type jsonb but expression is of type bytea Hint: You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.

if you are executing a native SQL DML statement.

### Native SQL DML statement

For instance, let's assume you want to do something like this:

```
int updateCount = entityManager.createNativeQuery("""
    UPDATE
        room_categories
    SET
        metadata = :metadata
    WHERE
        code = :code AND
        metadata ->> 'field1' is null            
    """)
.setParameter("code ", "123-ABC")
.setParameter(
    "metadata",
    new Metadata()
        .setField1("ABC")
        .setField2("123")
)
.executeUpdate();
```

The `bytea` type stands for byte array, and, since the `Metadata` type implements the `Serializable` interface, Hibernate falls back to using the `SerializableType` when no other type is more appropriate.

But, since you cannot bind a byte array to a `jsonb` column, PostgreSQL throws the aforementioned error.

### The fix

To fix it, we have to set the `JsonBinaryType` explicitly using the Hibernate-specific `setParameter` `Query` method:

```
int updateCount = entityManager.createNativeQuery("""
    UPDATE
        room_categories
    SET
        metadata = :metadata
    WHERE
        code = :code AND
        metadata ->> 'field1' is null            
    """)
.setParameter("code ", "123-ABC")
.unwrap(org.hibernate.query.Query.class)
.setParameter(
    "metadata",
    new Metadata()
        .setField1("ABC")
        .setField2("123"),
    JsonBinaryType.INSTANCE
)
.executeUpdate();
```

First, we had to `unwrap` the JPA `Query` to a Hibernate `org.hibernate.query.Query` and call the `setParameter` method that takes a Hibernate Type instance.

Now, Hibernate will know that the `metadata` parameter needs to be handled by the `JsonBinaryType`, and not by the `SerializableType`.

Comment: we had exactly this solution in our code for a while, now after update to springboot 2 and hibernate 6 it stopped working.

Answer (score 0):

Im coming a few years later but maybe useful for others:

In my case I fixed this problem by adding the following parameter to the connection string:

`stringtype=unspecified`