# How can I make some change on spring data underlying query

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I am using spring data in my project with Postgres as the Database. I have an entity that has a JSON field and I want to keep it as a `String` in the java context, but a `jsonb` in the database. Whenever I want to persist an instance of my entity the problem arises since hibernate is treating the JSON property as a `Basic` type and the underlying query does not change the `String` type to `jsonb` type.

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "a", catalog = "")
@TypeDef(name = "jsonb", typeClass = String.class)
public class A {
    @Type(type = "jsonb")
    @Column(name = "json-data", columnDefinition = "jsonb")
    private String myJsonData;
}
```

I find the solution for this problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53847917/postgresql-throws-column-is-of-type-jsonb-but-expression-is-of-type-bytea-with#62774773), but it needs to change the parameters of the underlying `PreparedStatement` query. So, I need to change the query and add `::jsonb` to make Postgres cast the parameter to `jsonb`. Is there any Annotation related to `@Type` to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `@ColumnTransformer` for this purpose.